# Unable to retrieve data from parallel ajax calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a function below (searchTerm) which is supposed to fetch data from two URL's simultaneously and display the result after both the calls are completed.

This is working fine when I call with only one parameter in `.when` (say `$.ajax(options1)`),

but as I need the output from both in parallel, I am calling both URL's and recording responses data1 and data2 in `.then` function, but now it is not getting called after the ajax calls are completed.

Can anyone tell if I am correct in this approach? If so, then why is the callback not getting executed?

```
var searchTerm = function() {

  var $a = $(this);
  var term = $("#searchbox").val();

  var options1 = {
      url: "someurl1",
      contentType: "application/json",
      data: JSON.stringify({
          searchString: term
      }),
      type: "post",
      dataType: "html"
  };

  var options2 = {
      url: "someurl2",
      contentType: "application/json",
      data: JSON.stringify({
          searchString: term
      }),
      type: "post",
      dataType: "html"
  };

  $.when($.ajax(options1), $.ajax(options2)).then(function(data1, data2) {
      alert("callbacks finished");
  });
```

**Info1:** 
        It seems any ajax call I specify as first argument is failing with 500 server error. I tried swapping options1 and options2, and now the call with options2 fails.

**Info2:** 
        The url that I have mentioned as part of options1 and options2 point to action methods in the same controller and they both return awaitable Task of (ActionResult) object. Can this be the problem here? Are the calls somehow blocking/interrupting each other over async requests?

**Info 3:** 
        Trying to provide more details to work with. The definition of the action methods are like this -

```
public async Task<ActionResult> someurl1(.....){
...
...
return await View(...);
}
```

Comment: can u try .done instead of .then and see if it works?

Comment: I did try it, but it had no affect.

Comment: did u check the network tab is both the requests are returning success?

Comment: I checked now, and it seems that the first call ($.ajax(options1)) is returning 500 Internal Server Error, but I'm not sure why. Why is it that this call is working fine standalone but not after specifying another argument to .when? Can you please suggest what might be the reason? I am checking from my side as well.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cnckfzpy/  everything works. Check the urls , and the ajax responses separately. Since you don't have error state handling, both calls must be successful.

Comment: @Holybreath You did Type:get not post as Sam did. Could this be his problem?

Comment: @pc-shooter used get, because of fiddle :P This was to prove that , the promise part is ok, the problem is with the ajax declaration.

Comment: Ahem.... Sure! I read the code as it were normal.... So must be on server side then

Comment: @Holybreath What seems to be the problem with ajax declaration? Just to give more information, I also swapped options1 and options2 in .when call, and still the first call is failed (with options2 now). It seems always the first call is failing. Still scratching my head over this.

Comment: I have added Info1 and Info2 in my original post. Can you guys help me figure out what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: you set `dataType` to "html" , are you sure that is the response you are expecting, and the server will give it to you? try `"json"`

Comment: Yes. Because I am returning an object of Task(ActionResult) and I have tested these functions standalone and they work perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the answer after debugging through all the subsequent calls. I was calling a common function from both action methods which uses a global variable to make external URL calls. Simply used the below locking mechanism to make my critical section thread-safe.

```
public static object Lock = new object();

lock (Lock) // added for thread safety purpose
{
    response_task = CallExtern(...)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try adding the option

```
async: false
```

to the ajax objects.

Comment: async: false doesn't work with promise objects. (and is generally a bad idea in *almost* every situation.)

Comment: Also, I do want both requests to be processed simultaneously, so async: false is not an option.